# Porque mi tabla no adquiere ambos comandos overflow-x e y

Tags: html5, scroll, bootstrap-3, html-tabla, bootstrap-table

Estoy usando **Bootstrap 3**, por eso utilizo `container`, `row` y c`ol-md-5`, ... no sé porqué, pero no logro nisiquiera fijar una altura a la tabla.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="card col-md-5"> 
<div   style="overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:scroll">

<h4 class="title header" align="center">Pasos</h4>
  
        
<table   class="table table-hover table-bordered" ">
         
 <thead>
  <th>
    <div class="checkbox">

       <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" >
       <label for="checkbox1"></label>

      
  </th>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Paso</th>
  <th>Resultado</th>

 </thead>

 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox2"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Paso1</td>
  <td>1:menu Digital......................................................................... </td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox3"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Paso 2</td>
  <td>3:Saldo total en el numero de cuenta..............................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox3"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Paso 3</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
       <label for="checkbox4"></label>
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Paso 4</td>
  <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

 </tr>
 
 
 
</table>
         
</div>  
</div> 
</div>       
</div> 

</table>
```

Este es mi tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores, el primero es que tienes una doble comilla en las clases de tu tabla después de `table-bordered`:

```
<table   class="table table-hover table-bordered" ">
```

También se te ha olvidado cerrar el `div` de esta parte en tu `thead` y colocar `tr` para agrupar tus *table heads*:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" >
            <label for="checkbox1"></label>
        </div>
    </th>
    ...
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Y al final de tu código estás cerrando otra vez la etiqueta `table`

---

*Snippet con tu código corregido aplicando una altura de 300px:*

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card col-md-5">
      <div style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:scroll; height: 300px">

        <h4 class="title header" align="center">Pasos</h4>


        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <div class="checkbox">

                  <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="checkbox1"></label>

                </div>

              </th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Paso</th>
              <th>Resultado</th>
            </tr>

          </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox2"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Paso1</td>
            <td>1:menu Digital......................................................................... </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox3"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Paso 2</td>
            <td>3:Saldo total en el numero de cuenta..............................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox3"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Paso 3</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox4"></label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Paso 4</td>
            <td>00: Volver al menu de inicio..................................................................................................................................</td>

          </tr>



        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, ya inclui el div y elimine las comillas dobles, no obstante, aun sigo sin poder fijar una altura a la tabla, la tabla solo sigue aumentando hacia abajo sin  mantenerse fija

Comment: Hice algunos arreglos, revisalos ahora si deberia funcionar

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, de verdad no sabia como realizar ese arreglo. Ya lo acomode y si se mantiene fija.

Comment: De nada, te recomiendo usar este validador de html para cuando tengas un problema similar ;)     https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Genial la usare para revisar mi codigo de ahora en adelante (Y), nuevamente muchas gracias por la revision/ayuda